# Explain this old trading saying

Tags: trading

I read in a trading book that

> An old saying on Wall Street notes that amateurs trade at the open
>   and professionals trade at the close.

what does it mean?

Comment: Kostas, one simple observation is that let us say "most" human "day traders", active traders, people who trade for a living, simply don't keep positions overnight. However as BobB points out the trading scene has changed dramatically in the first 2 decades of this century.  (I'm not sure if "day traders!" really exist anymore as a group!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An old saying on Wall Street notes that amateurs trade at the open and professionals trade at the close.

I don't know if he originated the saying but Alexander Elder wrote this in one of his trading books about 25 years ago.  The first and the last hour of the trading day are usually the most active (true) and Elder believed that amateurs are responsible for the first hour  and that pros are responsible for the last hour.  Perhaps this was true then but I doubt that now.

Some web sites also use such statements as part of their sales pitch, namely that if you trade with the pros (later in the day), you'll succeed at it.  Is that a reasonable conclusion for today?

Here are some stats that I've read over time and I do not offer them as currently accurate or with any sourcing:

- Institutions own over 80% of large cap stocks
- Institutions are currently responsible for over 70% of daily stock trading volume
- High Frequency Traders account for over 50% of daily stock trading

HFT did not exist 25 years ago and to whatever degree it existed, computerized algorithmic trading was in its infancy.  HFT trades all day long and I believe, so do institutional traders.  With all of this institutional ownership and trading volume, it's illogical to think that today, the pros are waiting all day to trade only toward  the close.

I'm neither and amateur nor a professional trader but I can attest to the fact that the first hours of the market are the most active for me.  Occasionally I have a multi-legged option/stock position that I am delta neutral trading and the gyrations needed for profitability occur more often than not in this time period.  If that's due to amateurs, thank you.  But I think otherwise.  Traders trade the news as it occurs not at pre-selected times of the day.